# Can you create a new SQL buffer in Emacs if one already exists?

Tags: sql, emacs, sql-mode

Let's say you have a *SQL* buffer already open in Emacs that is connected to a specific server and database.  Now, your intention is to connect to a different server and database while keeping your other SQL buffer process active.

How exactly can you create a new *SQL* buffer process without killing your original SQL buffer? Can this be done? Is there a way to instead change your connection info for the existing buffer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running:

```
M-x sql-rename-buffer
```

On a connected `*SQL*` buffer will rename the current buffer after the current connection.  So:

```
*SQL*
```

Becomes:

```
*SQL user/database*
```

You can then do:

```
M-x sql-mysql
```

Or whatever your flavor of DB is to create another SQL buffer.

Answer (score 2):

As a slight simplification, you can just do:

```
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook 'sql-rename-buffer)
```

(I.e., you don't need the `lambda`).

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if someone like me likes another representation of the connection,
here is mine.
This is how my sql buffers named: "driver://user@server/database"

```
(defun sql-make-alternate-buffer-name ()
  (concat (concat (prin1-to-string sql-interactive-product) "://")
      (if (string= "" sql-user)
          (if (string= "" (user-login-name))
          ()
        (concat (user-login-name) "/"))
        (concat sql-user "@"))
      (concat sql-server "/")
      (if (string= "" sql-database)
          (if (string= "" sql-server)
          (system-name)
        sql-server)
        sql-database)))
```

*SQL* buffers created in sql-interactive-mode, which runs sql-interactive-mode-hook,
so there is no need to run sql-rename-buffer manually

```
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook
    (lambda () (sql-rename-buffer)))
```